# Jackson customize Map ValueInstantiator

Tags: jackson

By default Jackson creates instances of `java.util.LinkedHashMap` when deserializing any `Map` types.  How can this be customized to have Jackson create a different Map implementation, but still continue to use its default Map deserializer?

Answer (score 5):

There are multiple ways to do this, but probably the easiest is just to specify what class should be used as concrete implementation of an abstract class. So something like:

```
SimpleModule myModule = new SimpleModule(...);
myModule.addAbstractTypeMapping(Map.class, SomeOtherMap.class);
objectMapper.registerModule(myModule);
```

this works for both defaulting of common abstract types (`List`, `Collection`, `Map`) as well as for specifying concrete implementations of custom interfaces and abstract classes.